# Gulp [ERR_ASSERTION]: таcк работает через раз

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Gulp-таск

```
gulp.task('update production js', gulp.series(

    done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },
    del.sync(outputJsSelection),
    'webpack'
));
```

работает через раз. В случае ошибки, показывает следующее:

```
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^
// Это не таск, NoJsRequest - это просто JavaScript - файл!
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\public\open\js\NoJsRequest.js
    at getFunction (C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:15:5)
    at map (C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\node_modules\arr-map\index.js:20:14)
    at normalizeArgs (C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:22:10)
    at Gulp.series (C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\node_modules\undertaker\lib\series.js:13:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\gulpfile.js:143:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Перед тем, как я сделал таск `update production js`, `webpack` работал нормально (да и сейчас дело не в нём).

Дополнительная информация:

```
const   gulp = require('gulp'),
        webpack = require('webpack'),
        del = require('del');

let outputJsSelection = 
[ 'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\example.loc\\public\\open\\js\\**\\*.*',
  'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\example.loc\\public\\admin\\js\\**\\*.*' ];
```

Кстати, тоже самое и с таском 'update production styles':

```
gulp.task('update production styles', gulp.series(

    done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },
    del.sync(HPath.outputCssSelection),
    'styles'
));

assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

// 01_Top.css - это же не таск!!
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\public\open\css\01_Top.css
```

### Результаты самостоятельной отладки

Да, действительно, если убрать таски `styles` или `webpack`, всё будет работать корректно каждый раз:

```
gulp.task('update production styles', gulp.series(

    done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },
    del.sync(outputCssSelection),
    //'styles'
));
```

Но если вернуть таски `styles` и `webpack`, то даже строка `done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },` не будет выполнена. Отладочный вариант таска `update production styles`:

```
gulp.task('update production styles', gulp.series(

    done1 => { console.log('ok1'); done1(); },
    done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },
    done2 => { console.log('ok2'); done2(); },
    del.sync(outputCssSelection),
    done3 => { console.log('ok3'); done3(); },
    'styles'
));
```

Случай с корректным выполнением таска (срабатывает, когда в выходной папке нет css или js-файлов):

```
λ gulp "update production styles"
[10:46:23] Using gulpfile C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\gulpfile.js
[10:46:23] Starting 'update production styles'...
[10:46:23] Starting '<anonymous>'...
ok1
[10:46:23] Finished '<anonymous>' after 1.69 ms
[10:46:23] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[10:46:23] Finished '<anonymous>' after 967 μs
[10:46:23] Starting '<anonymous>'...
ok2
[10:46:23] Finished '<anonymous>' after 1.55 ms
[10:46:23] Starting '<anonymous>'...
ok3
[10:46:23] Finished '<anonymous>' after 1.09 ms
[10:46:23] Starting 'styles'...
[10:46:27] Finished 'styles' after 3.31 s
[10:46:27] Finished 'update production styles' after 3.32 s
```

Случай некорректной работы таска (ни одного `ok` в консоли):

```
λ gulp "update production styles"
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\public\open\css\01_Top.css
```

### Обновление

Приведу листинг двух выше описанных тасков. Код тасков `styles` и `webpack` добавлять не буду, так как они слишком большой и работает исправно.

```
gulp.task('update production styles', gulp.series(

    done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },
    del.sync([ 
        'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\example.loc\\public\\open\\css\\**\\*',
        'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\example.loc\\public\\admin\\css\\**\\*' ]),
    'styles'
));

gulp.task('update production js', gulp.series(

    done => { isDevelopment = false; done (); },
    del.sync([ 
        'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\example.loc\\public\\open\\js\\**\\*',
        'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\example.loc\\public\\admin\\js\\**\\*' ]),
    'webpack'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в вашем `del`, он по идее выдаёт ошибку когда удаляете папку а там есть файлы. Попробуйте использовать `rimraf = require('rimraf')`
Таск будет примерно таким

```
// Таск для предварительной очистки (удаления) production-папки 
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.dist.css.dest + '/*', cb);
    rimraf(paths.dist.img.dest + '/*', cb);
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! А что в этом страшного-то, что в папке есть файлы? Я до этого без проблем очищал папки с файлами примерно таким способом: `return del.sync('dist')`, и ничего не падало.

Comment: @БоковГлеб `del` может ругаться, если считает что вы пытаетесь удалить текущую рабочую директорию, нужно ему передавать параметр `force`, подробнее в доках. У самого тоже были глюки с этим `del`-ом. А так проблему решили, дело было в этом?

Comment: @Daniyarov, c `force` не вышло. Заметил ещё одну странную вещь: `update production js` никогда не запустится (будет падать и выводить сообщение `Task never defined: C:\OpenServer\domains\example.loc\public\open\css\01_Top.css`), если в папке со стилями есть файлы, при этом удаляет файлы именно в папке css, хотя должен удалять файлы в папке `js`. Лишь после этого неудачного запуска он уже удаляет именно скрипты. Glob-пути, естественно, проверил - всё нормально. Я попробую `rimraf`, но сначала хочу понять происходящее.

Comment: @БоковГлеб "при этом удаляет файлы именно в папке css" -
 `del.sync(outputCssSelection)` на это обратите внимание, "будет падать и выводить сообщение Task never defined" это из-за того что зависимые таски, нужно определять в начале. Воообще выложите весь скрипт, и скажите какой таск запускаете

Comment: @Daniyarov, С ошибкой `Task never defined` я, конечно знаком, но в данном случае отнюдь не тривиально перепутанный порядок тасков (оба таска идут в самом конце `gulpfile.js`). Удивление вызывают как минимум две вещи: 1) Сообщение об ошибке указывает не на таск, а на стилевой файл. 2) таск всё же файлы удаляет несмотря на ошибку, но не те, которые надо. Я добавил код обоих тасков в конец, но в принципе, он уже в виде фрагментов был в вопросе...